# Creating SQL query to search inside multiple unidirectional one-to-many table with dynamic where clause/search criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, java-8

I've four tables. One is the `main_table` and there are other three tables are mapped with main_table as one-to-many mapping. (provide correction if my explanation is incorrect)
`child_1, child_2, child_3` are mapped by with `unique_key` of `main_table`

(Database to which I'm connecting is `postgres`.)

```
main_table (
    unique_key          character varying(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    --few more fields
);          

child_1 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(255),
    main_table_unique_key character varying(100) REFERENCES main_table(unique_key) NOT NULL
);


child_2 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(255),
    main_table_unique_key character varying(100) REFERENCES main_table(unique_key) NOT NULL
);

child_3 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(255),
    type character varying(255),
    main_table_unique_key character varying(100) REFERENCES main_table(unique_key) NOT NULL
);
```

I've multiple dynamic search criteria. So based on that I'm generating the SQL inner join query to fetch records.
The data-structure for search criteria is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "child_1": "Dollar Sales",
    "child_2": "Retailer",
    "child_3": [
      {
        "type": "XYZ",
        "name": "name abc"
      },
      {
        "type": "foo",
        "name": "bar"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "child_1": "EUR Sales ",
    "child_2": null,
    "child_3": [
      {
        "type": "XYZ",
        "name": "name pqr"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "child_1": "USD Sales",
    "child_2": "State",
    "child_3": []
  }
]
```

Each top level array item I'm calling as single `search criteria`. So in above example ther 3 `search criteria`.
The `child_1` can not be null. But `child_2` can be and `child_3` can have zero or more records.
The twist is whenever I'm retrieving result in the case there are `1 or more child_3` in single item I've to make match that only those many numbers of record present for `unique_key` in `child_3` table.

I'm not very good with SQL so currently what I'm doing is flattening the child_3. So if there are two items in `child_2` I'm creating two search criteria for first array item.

My current JAVA+ SQL Approach is:
Here is the way I've implemented it:

1. Make a inner join query having `child_1= Dollar Sales && child_2 = Retailer  && type = XYZ && name= name abc`
2. Store the result from 1 into `resultArray`.
3. Make a inner join query having `child_1= Dollar Sales && child_2 = Retailer  && type = foo && name= bar`
4. Store the result from 3 into `resultArray`.
5. Group by the `resultArray` having `count =  child_3.size()`
6. Select records from `resultArray` satisfying the 5 into `finalResultArray`.
7. Above steps I'm doing for each search criteria.

In case you need my code, it is as follow:

```
List<ResponseItem> multipleChild3Response = search.getChild3()
        .stream()
        .map(child3 -> buildAndRetrieve(search.child1(), search.child2(), child3))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Set<String> matchingUniqueKey = multipleChild3Response
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResponseItem::getUniqueKey, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == noOfBos)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

if (!matchingUniqueKey.isEmpty()) {
    List<ResponseItem> matchingChild3Result = matchingUniqueKey
            .stream()
            .map(uniqueKey -> multipleChild3Response
                    .stream()
                    .filter(mainTableObj -> mainTableObj.getUniqueKey().equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueKey))
                    .findAny()
            )
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    finalResultArray.addAll(matchingChild3Result);
    }
```

`buildAndRetrieve` function generates the SQL query as below:

```
select n.unique_key,
       n.document,
       --few more fields only from main_table
from main_table n 
inner JOIN child_1 nm on n.unique_key = nm.main_table_unique_key
--inner JOIN child_2 na on n.unique_key = na.main_table_unique_key --this is selected if child_2 is not null
inner join child_3 nbo on n.unique_key = nbo.main_table_unique_key --this is selected if child_3 is not null
where ( nm.name='Dollar Sales' and na.name='Retailer' nbo.type='XYZ' and nbo.name='name abc');
```

Currently I'm following JAVA(mostly this only) & SQL approach to solve above problem.
How can I completely write above JAVA logic into the `SQL` using some `with` or `joins` ? Which will help me in retrieving result in `single SQL query` instead of firing query multiple times.

Comment: Note: don't use a large character column as primary key: `unique_key          character varying(100) PRIMARY KEY,`

Comment: @wildplasser. Ok. I'll add one more column as `id` which will be mapped as primary key & will add `UNIQUE` constraint on `unique_key`. will that make sense ?

Comment: Yes. And also the three FKs that refer to it.